# SP2013 add gradient IE

Tags: css, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am working on branding SP2013 and everything is working except for IE9 support the gradient. I tried adding in,

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

but it did not fix the issue and SP2013 dev console did not like the syntax. Is there a way to do this or should I just do it via an image tag?

Answer (score 0):

CSS gradients were added in IE 10. [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)

If you want to do this using CSS-only, you'll need to use a filter for <= IE 9.

Comment: Sorry but you did not read my post at all. I have included the filter code. My question is where in SP2013 do I put the filter so it will be used.